# How to insert array into mysql using PDO and bindParam?

Tags: mysql, multidimensional-array, pdo

I'm using the following code. The code works, but I want to change it so that it uses bindparam

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$stqid=array();

    for ($i=0; $i<$array_count; $i++){
    $stqid[$i][0]=$lastInsertValue;
    $stqid[$i][1]=$qid[$i][0];
    $stqid[$i][2]=$qid[$i][1];
    }

$values = array();
    foreach ($stqid as $rowValues) {
        foreach ($rowValues as $key => $rowValue) {
        $rowValues[$key] = $rowValues[$key];  
        }

    $values[] = "(" . implode(', ', $rowValues) . ")";
    }

$count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO qresults(instance, qid, result) VALUES  ".implode (', ', $values)); 
$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I replaced the following

```
$count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO qresults(instance, qid, result) VALUES  ".implode (', ', $values));
```

with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO qresults (instance, qid, result) VALUES (:an_array)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':an_array', implode(',', $values),PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

but the insert doesn't work anymore (I didn't get any error messages though).

**QUESTION:** What am I doing wrong? How can I rewrite the code to use bindParam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to create a statement and bind a param.

Statement are great because it potentially nullify any kind of SQL injection. And it does it by removing the concept of a query being only seen as a string. The SQL query is seen as a string with a parameter list and an the associated data as binded variables.
So the query is not only text, but text + data.

I mean:

This simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE val="$param"
```

It is not safe because the query is only viewed as a string. And if $param is not checked, it is a SQLi hole.

But when create a statement, your query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE val=:param
```

Then you use bindparam to specify the value a :param. Which mean the value is not appended to the query string, but the query is already parsed and the data is provided.

In your case, you bind to the param :array an imploded array (I assume "data1", "data2", etc..). Which is only one parameter with the value as a string ( "data1, data2, data3..." ), so it will only result in one insert and not multiple insertions.

You can change your statement generation by generating a query with enough parameters to handle your array

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO qresults (instance, qid, result) VALUES ( :val0, :val1, :val2, ...)";
```

Then loop on your array and call the bindparam method for each parameters.

```
$count = 0;
foreach($values as $val)
{
   $stmt->bindParam(":val$count", $val,PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $count++;

}
```

This will work.

**Edit**: This solution show how it works for a one dimensional array, but can be easily extended to your problem by tweaking the statement query generation and modify the bindparam loop.

Your statement should looks like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO qresults (instance, qid, result) VALUES (:val0, :val1, :val2) , (:val3, :val4, :val5), ...";
```

You just have to count the number of element in your base array.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. It is much easier to understand now :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this when the number of values to be inserted is different each time?

Comment: Yeah you just have to generate your query string according to your needs and bind the params matching those of the query you generated