# Why am I getting error SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: ? How can I fix it?

Tags: mysql, arrays, pdo

Based on this question  [How to insert array into mysql using PDO and bindParam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858073/how-to-insert-array-into-mysql-using-pdo-and-bindparam)

I'm trying to insert values of an array into mysql via PDO.
I'm having a hard time of it, because I keep getting the following error.
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
for this line `$stmt->execute();`

I'm guessing the problem has something to do with this line

`$stmt->bindParam(':val$count', $val,PDO::PARAM_STR);` Specifically 'val$count', but I'm not sure exactly what is going wrong.

**QUESTION:** What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Anyway here is the code I'm using along with the sample array.

```
$lastInsertValue=87;
$qid[0][0]=1;
$qid[0][1]=1;
$qid[1][0]=2;
$qid[1][1]="null";
$qid[2][0]=3;
$qid[2][1]=0;
$array_count = count($qid);

if (isset($lastInsertValue)) 
{ 
    try 
    {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $stqid=array();
            $a=0;       
                for ($i=0; $i<$array_count; $i++)
                {       
                    $stqid[$a]=$lastInsertValue;
                    $a++;
                    $stqid[$a]=$qid[$i][0];
                    $a++;
                    $stqid[$a]=$qid[$i][1];
                    $a++;
                }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO qresults (instance, qid, result) VALUES ( :val0, :val1, :val2)";
            $count = 0;
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);    
                foreach ($stqid as $val)
                {
                    $stmt->bindParam(':val$count', $val,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $count++;           
                }
            $stmt->execute();
            $dbh = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yikes, so many issues.

1. Your array building is so verbose. Try this

   ```
   $stqid = array();
   foreach ($qid as $qidArr) {
       $stqid[] = $lastInsertValue; // no idea why you repeat this
       $stqid[] = $qidArr[0];
       $stqid[] = $qidArr[1];
   }
   ```
2. Use positional placeholders if you're simply relying on number of arguments

   ```
   $sql = 'INSERT INTO ... VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
   ```
3. `bindParam` uses references which you are overwriting with each loop iteration. You would want to use `bindValue()` instead
4. Your query only has 3 placeholders but your `$stqid` array has 9 items. This is the source of your error.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback. I know the code ain't great. I tend to bash it out then go over it rather then sit staring at the computer screen (although I do that too!). I'll probably leave some more comments, but I have to do some more research first.

Comment: How can I insert the values when I don't know how many items the array will contain? I had wanted to insert multiple rows (3 items per row), but the number of rows to insert each time will be different.

Answer (score 2):

You have single quotes around a variable, which will be treated as the variable name `$count` (not the value), try concatenating the variable to the string. Give this a try:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':val' . $count, $val,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: This was indeed part of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
      for ($i=0; $i<$array_count; $i++)
            {       
                $stqid[$a]=$lastInsertValue;
                $a++;
                $stqid[$a]=$qid[$i][0];
                $a++;
                $stqid[$a]=$qid[$i][1];
                $a++;
            }
```

so in case `$i = 2`, it will add `$stqid[6]`, `$stqid[7]`, `$stqid[8]`  so

```
            foreach ($stqid as $val)
            {
                $stmt->bindParam(':val$count', $val,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $count++;           
            }
```

will give you `:val0` to `:val8`

In your query you have only `:val0` to `:val2`.

Also having multiple values in one field in database is bad. Don't do it. Try to redesign your DB differently

EDIT: bad math in the morning... sorry

Comment: Sorry. What do you mean by multiple values in one field?

Comment: hmm ... probably wrongly understood `$stmt->bindParam(':an_array', implode(',', $values),PDO::PARAM_STR);` in your previous question. Looks like you tried there to insert multiple values divided by `,` into one field. But after some coffee i think you are trying to insert multiple rows at once using array. Am I right or should i get more coffee

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858073/how-to-insert-array-into-mysql-using-pdo-and-bindparam I was trying to insert multiple rows at once using a multidimensional array. The array contained values for instance, qid and result. I wanted to make it safer by using bindparam. This question is just a result of me playing around with that question's answer and trying to understand it.